# Angular.js tutorial running e2e test using protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, testing, protractor

I am following the Angular tutorial https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial
When I get to the last bit on the first page - "e2e using protractor", I do "npm run protractor" in a new command window with the local site running and karma running, but I get the below error log:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'c:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'c:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'protractor' ]
2 info using npm@2.11.2
3 info using node@v0.12.5
4 verbose run-script [ 'preprotractor', 'protractor', 'postprotractor' ]
5 info preprotractor angular-phonecat@0.0.0
6 verbose unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
7 info protractor angular-phonecat@0.0.0
8 verbose unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
9 info angular-phonecat@0.0.0 Failed to exec protractor script
10 verbose stack Error: angular-phonecat@0.0.0 protractor: `protractor test/protractor-conf.js`
10 verbose stack Exit status 1
10 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (c:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\lifecycle.js:213:16)
10 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:110:17)
10 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (c:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\spawn.js:24:14)
10 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
10 verbose stack     at maybeClose (child_process.js:1015:16)
10 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1087:5)
11 verbose pkgid angular-phonecat@0.0.0
12 verbose cwd c:\Program Files (x86)\GitExtensions\angular-phonecat
13 error Windows_NT 6.1.7601
14 error argv "c:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "c:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "protractor"
15 error node v0.12.5
16 error npm  v2.11.2
17 error code ELIFECYCLE
18 error angular-phonecat@0.0.0 protractor: `protractor test/protractor-conf.js`
18 error Exit status 1
19 error Failed at the angular-phonecat@0.0.0 protractor script 'protractor test/protractor-conf.js'.
19 error This is most likely a problem with the angular-phonecat package,
19 error not with npm itself.
19 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
19 error     protractor test/protractor-conf.js
19 error You can get their info via:
19 error     npm owner ls angular-phonecat
19 error There is likely additional logging output above.
20 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. It seems that the chromedriver.zip archive that comes with the angular-phonecat package is corrupted, making the installation of chromedriver impossible.
You can go to http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html to download a clean archive of the chromedriver for your platform.

Go to this folder: yourwebRoot\angular-phonecat\node_modules\protractor\selenium
Remove the archive **chromedriver_2.10** from the folder and extract the one you downloaded here. 
 In your terminal type npm run protractor to run the e2e test again. It should now work.

Comment: alternatively, you could install the latest version of chrome driver via NPM.